# Who were the founders/owners of the Société Anonyme de Recherches et d’Exploitations Minière en Côte d’Ivoire (SAREMCI)?

Tags: business-history, west-africa

According to [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/02255189.2020.1799339), SAREMCI was "created by a group of Parisian diamond dealers and jewellers". Does anyone know the names of any of the founders or of the firm's leadership from 1945 to 1975?

Comment: This is going to be difficult to dig up online I think. The [Archives nationales d'outre-mer](http://www.archivesnationales.culture.gouv.fr/anom/fr/) in Aix-en-Provence might have something. You could also try looking for old copies of [Les Cahiers d’Outre-Mer](https://journals.openedition.org/com/) (I used them in Abidjan at the ORSTOM research centre, but ORSTOM is not online - it may even be closed now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 56 of [Annuaire des entreprises coloniales 1951-AOF et Togo](https://entreprises-coloniales.fr/afrique-occidentale/AEC_1951-AOF-Togo.pdf) cites the following for SAREMCI

> 348 bis — Société anonyme de recherches et d'exploitations minières de la Côte
> d'ivoire (SAREMCI),
> Siège social : 8, rue La Fayette, PARIS (9e),
> Société anonyme au capital de 60 millions de fr. en actions de 1.000 fr., titulaire de droit, miniers dans le cercle de Korhogo (Côte-d'Ivoire)[diamants, selon Suret-Canale,1945-1960, p. 243].
> [contrôlée par Eknayan, 8, rue Lafayette, Paris]

> *348 bis - Société anonyme de recherches et d'exploitations minières de la Côte d'ivoire (SAREMCI),
> Registered office: 8, rue La Fayette, PARIS (9e),
> Société anonyme with capital of 60 million fr. in shares of 1,000 fr., holder of mining rights in the Korhogo circle (Ivory Coast) [diamonds, according to Suret-Canale,1945-1960, p. 243].
> [*controlled by Eknayan, 8, rue Lafayette, Paris*].* translation courtesy of [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#fr/en/348%20bis%20%E2%80%94%20Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20anonyme%20de%20recherches%20et%20d%27exploitations%20mini%C3%A8res%20de%20la%20C%C3%B4te%20d%27ivoire%20(SAREMCI)%2C%0ASi%C3%A8ge%20social%20%3A%208%2C%20rue%20La%20Fayette%2C%20PARIS%20(9e)%2C%0ASoci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20anonyme%20au%20capital%20de%2060%20millions%20de%20fr.%20en%20actions%20de%201.000%20fr.%2C%20titulaire%20de%20droit%2C%20miniers%20dans%20le%20cercle%20de%20Korhogo%20(C%C3%B4te-d%27Ivoire)%5Bdiamants%2C%20selon%20Suret-Canale%2C1945-1960%2C%20p.%20243%5D.%0A%5Bcontr%C3%B4l%C3%A9e%20par%20Eknayan%2C%208%2C%20rue%20Lafayette%2C%20Paris%5D)

This [German Wikipedia entry for Myran Eknayan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myran_Eknayan) cites the following

> Myran Garabet Eknayan (* 27. September 1892 in Paris; † 19. Juni 1985 in Neuilly-sur-Seine) war ein Diamantenhändler und Kunstsammler armenischer Herkunft.
> Myran Eknayan kam 1892 in Paris zur Welt. Als alternative Schreibweisen des Vornamens findet sich in der Literatur auch Mihran oder Mirant. Die armenische Kaufmannsfamilie Eknayan stammte ursprünglich aus dem Osmanischen Reich. Sein Vorfahr Atamik Eknayan (1847–1925) ließ sich 1872 in Paris nieder. Er begründete 1893 eine Diamantschleiferei am Boulevard de la Villette, die später nach Neuilly-sur-Seine umsiedelte. Die Firma unterhielt zudem Geschäftsräume an der vornehmen Pariser Place Vendôme, wo Myran Eknayan als Diamantenhändler arbeitete. Er war zudem Präsident (président directeur) der Gesellschaft SAREMCI (Société anonyme de recherches et d’exploitation minières en Côte d’Ivoire), die Diamantenminen in der Elfenbeinküste betrieb.

> ***Myran Garabet Eknayan** (* 27 September 1892 in Paris; † 19 June 1985 in Neuilly-sur-Seine) was a diamond dealer and art collector of Armenian origin.
> Myran Eknayan was born in Paris in 1892. Alternative spellings of the first name in literature include Mihran or Mirant. The Armenian merchant family Eknayan originally came from the Ottoman Empire. His ancestor Atamik Eknayan (1847-1925) settled in Paris in 1872. In 1893, he founded a diamond-cutting company on the Boulevard de la Villette, which later moved to Neuilly-sur-Seine. The company also maintained business premises in Paris' posh Place Vendôme, where Myran Eknayan worked as a diamond dealer. He **was** also **president (président directeur) of SAREMCI (Société anonyme de recherches et d'exploitation minières en Côte d'Ivoire), a company that operated diamond mines in Côte d'Ivoire.*** [DeepL translation](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#de/en/Myran%20Garabet%20Eknayan%20(*%2027.%20September%201892%20in%20Paris%3B%20%E2%80%A0%2019.%20Juni%201985%20in%20Neuilly-sur-Seine)%20war%20ein%20Diamantenh%C3%A4ndler%20und%20Kunstsammler%20armenischer%20Herkunft.%0AMyran%20Eknayan%20kam%201892%20in%20Paris%20zur%20Welt.%20Als%20alternative%20Schreibweisen%20des%20Vornamens%20findet%20sich%20in%20der%20Literatur%20auch%20Mihran%20oder%20Mirant.%20Die%20armenische%20Kaufmannsfamilie%20Eknayan%20stammte%20urspr%C3%BCnglich%20aus%20dem%20Osmanischen%20Reich.%20Sein%20Vorfahr%20Atamik%20Eknayan%20(1847%E2%80%931925)%20lie%C3%9F%20sich%201872%20in%20Paris%20nieder.%20Er%20begr%C3%BCndete%201893%20eine%20Diamantschleiferei%20am%20Boulevard%20de%20la%20Villette%2C%20die%20sp%C3%A4ter%20nach%20Neuilly-sur-Seine%20umsiedelte.%20Die%20Firma%20unterhielt%20zudem%20Gesch%C3%A4ftsr%C3%A4ume%20an%20der%20vornehmen%20Pariser%20Place%20Vend%C3%B4me%2C%20wo%20Myran%20Eknayan%20als%20Diamantenh%C3%A4ndler%20arbeitete.%20Er%20war%20zudem%20Pr%C3%A4sident%20(pr%C3%A9sident%20directeur)%20der%20Gesellschaft%20SAREMCI%20(Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20anonyme%20de%20recherches%20et%20d%E2%80%99exploitation%20mini%C3%A8res%20en%20C%C3%B4te%20d%E2%80%99Ivoire)%2C%20die%20Diamantenminen%20in%20der%20Elfenbeink%C3%BCste%20betrieb.)